# ejecutar script.py, visualizar salida en navegador web

Tags: python, json, webservice, url

tengo una duda: estoy ejecutando en consola un script.py, la salida del script, esta en formato JSON. pero quiero poder ver la salida a través de un navegador web (formato JSON).

Aqui estoy ejecutando el script python
[root@test]# python3 salida_json.py
[
{"Event": "Connected", "LastReboot": "8552", "Privilege": "monitoring, "Status": "Normal", "Uptime": "55637", "content": ""}
,

Cuando activo un pulsador en la misma consola me envia esta respuesta:
{"Code": "", "IDName": "test01", "IDNum": "20", "Event": "Connected", "Status": "Active", "Language": "es", "content": ""},

Comment: Los navegadores modernos te pueden mostrar un archivo JSON, local u obtenido desde cualquier URL, con formato y sin formato. No se entiende la duda.

Comment: Por favor incluye el código relacionado con tu pregunta para poder darte una respuesta específica a tu problema. No queda claro si has creado un archivo *json* o has imprimido el resultado en la *salida estándar*, sin crear un archivo. Primero tienes que crear el archivo y luego abrirlo en el navegador. TIenes una buena respuesta por parte de [eniel.rod](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/205377/eniel-rod)

Answer (score 1):

Una forma simple es guardar ese archivo JSON y luego abrirlo en el navegador desde Python

```
import webbrowser   
webbrowser.open('file:///path/to/file.json', new=2)
```

Puede que este código le abra el software que tiene asociada la extensión .json en lugar del navegador. Si le pasa esto, puede hacer lo siguiente

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.register('firefox', None,
    webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser("/usr/bin/firefox")) #en Windows C://path/to/firefox.exe
    
webbrowser.get('firefox').open('file:///path/to/file.json', new=2)
```

> Si new es 0, la URL se abre en la misma ventana del navegador si es
> posible. Si new es 1, se abre una nueva ventana del navegador si es
> posible. Si new es 2, se abre una nueva pestaña si es posible.

Referencias
[How to Open URL in Chrome Browser from Python Application?](https://pythonexamples.org/python-open-url-in-chrome-browser/)
[How to open a web browser using Python](http://net-informations.com/python/net/browser.htm)

Comment: [root@test]# python3 salida_json.py
[
  {"Event": "Connected", "LastReboot": "8552", "Privilege": "monitoring, "Status": "Normal", "Uptime": "55637", "content": ""}
,

  {"Code": "", "IDName": "test01", "IDNum": "20", "Event": "Connected", "Status": "Active", "Language": "es", "content": ""},

Comment: Aqui estoy ejecutando el script python
[root@test]# python3 salida_json.py
[
  {"Event": "Connected", "LastReboot": "8552", "Privilege": "monitoring, "Status": "Normal", "Uptime": "55637", "content": ""}
,

Cuando activo un pulsador en la misma consola me envia esta respuesta:
  {"Code": "", "IDName": "test01", "IDNum": "20", "Event": "Connected", "Status": "Active", "Language": "es", "content": ""},

Comment: @JulioHectorAguilarRenteria le recomiendo editar el script Python para que guarde la salida en un archivo y lance el navegador. Si no tiene permitido modificar el archivo, intente `python3 salida_json.py > file.json`, aunque ahí ya pierde automatización. También puede hacer su propio script que ejecute a salida_json.py, capture su salida, la guarde en un archivo .json, y luego lo abra en el navegador.

Comment: hola, cuando ejecuto el script salida_json.py, se queda monitoreando por nuevos datos en tiempo real, por lo cual si guardo a file.json, no podria realizar el monitoreo en tiempo real.